# How to loop a Select by Attribute to use in a Select by Location?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am new to python scripting and I need help.

I am trying to select one row at a time on a shapefile that contains buffer rings around sites we are working on (some rings overlap), and for each site buffer I need to select by location and extract the castrate parcels that intersect.

At the moment the code runs through ok but it outputs the entire cadastre dataset for each site and does not appear to select each row to run in the select by location function. What am i doing wrong?

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Cadastre,'cadastre_lyr')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Buffer_5km, 'buflayer')

field = "SiteName"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor('buflayer')
for row in cursor:
    out = (row.getValue(field))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("buflayer", "NEW_SELECTION")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('cadastre_lyr',"INTERSECT", 'buflayer')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('cadastre_lyr', CadastreOut + "Cadastre_" + str(out) + ".shp")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CadastreOut = "C:\\"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Cadastre, "cadastre_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Buffer_5km, "buflayer")

field = "SiteName"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("buflayer")

for row in cursor:
    geometry = row.getValue("Shape")
    out = str(row.getValue(field))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("cadastre_lyr", "INTERSECT", geometry)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("cadastre_lyr", CadastreOut + "Cadastre_" + out + ".shp")
```

I'm not sure what your variable CadastreOut is set to, so I put it at the beginning.

Comment: @Ryan no problem, let me know if you have any questions about it.